# How to execute the included file after performing some action

Tags: javascript, php

I have one html file called "usera_authentication.html" in which i am entering 3 text field's data. On sumit button it is redirecting to "usera.php".
usera.php have below code.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pane" id="pane_0">
            <img src="video_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="pane" id="pane_1" style="display: none">
            <input type="button" value="Call Customer Care" id="call" class="btn btn-info btn-default btn-block">
        </div>
        <div class="pane" id="pane_2" style="display: none">
            <div id="video_container"></div>
            <input type="button" value="Stop Call" id="quit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default btn-block">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var userid="<?php echo isset($_POST['userid'])?$_POST['userid']:'';?>";
        var userName="<?php echo isset($_POST['userName'])?$_POST['userName']:'';?>";
        var remoteUserId="<?php echo isset($_POST['remoteUserId'])?$_POST['remoteUserId']:'';?>";

    </script>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['userid']) && $_POST['userid']!=""){ echo "in"; ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="conference.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.bistri.com/bistri.conference.min.js"></script>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

I am getting data in $_POST and it is initialize in variables perfectly.
Now those variables "userid,userName,remoteUserId" are used in conference.js file and using those variable connection process happening.

Now my issue is connection.js file is executing before the variable initialized from $_POST and due to that i am not getting correct value in connection.js file and connection not happening.

Does anybody have any idea how to resolve my above issue?

Overall my purpose is pass the data from usera_authentication.html file and use those data in connection.js file which is included in usera.php. I can not directly pass to connection.js file because it is global file which will also use from userb.php file same as usera.php.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue. Actually i have made one mistake in variable name and due to that i was not able to get the correct data in js file.